# Install Resharper Extension using PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, plugins, resharper

We are looking at using PowerShell provisioning scripts for developer VMs and can install ReSharper via PowerShell, but I have not yet found anything on how to add the extensions for VS (currently hoping to add StyleCop) so that the developer experience is set up and configured as completely as possible without manual intervention.

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx

Comment: Hi, I have looked at the link and it seems to require a "appx" file, which the downloaded Resharper Stylecop extension I have doesn't have.

Is there some additional step I am missing?  So far the only thing I have seen for adding the resharper extensions is via resharper itself within Visual Studio - but that kind of defeats the point of what I want to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a rough idea how to continue with that, since I've tried to achieve the same, but didn't have time to complete it:

1. Download ReSharper installer. Either via fixed URL, or parse the [service output](https://data.services.jetbrains.com/products/releases?code=RSU&latest=true) to get the latest version.
2. Generate a command-line invocation string. Similar to: `installer.exe /VsVersion=12.0;14.0;15.0 /SpecificProductNames=ReSharper /Silent=True`
3. Invoke the installer.

For plugins:

1. Download the plugin: `https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/<packageName>`
2. Extract to `%localappdata%\jetbrains\plugins`.
3. Adapt the config file in `AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharperPlatformVsXX\XX`
4. Reinvoke the installer.

I'm not 100% sure though about all of this. The second installer invocation might include an additional switch, but you should find out by manually installing a plugin, and checking with ProcMon.